# Rviz interact mode stuck, can't move mouse without rotating environment

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm walking through the MoveIt quickstart tutorial and have launched Rviz. However, when the Rviz GUI is running, if my mouse moves, the environment rotates with the movement. I know this isn't the default behavior in Rviz, and I don't really know why this is occurring. I've checked that sticky keys, slow keys, and bounce keys are all off. I've also restarting Rviz two times, but the same issue occurs.

In the middle of the Rviz grid, there's a small blue disk. If I click anywhere on the screen, the disk goes away. However, if I move the mouse, the disk reappears. I'd post an image, but I don't have enough points.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 + Melodic and Rviz 1.13.9. I'd be happy to share more information, but I don't know what else to share.

Aside from this issue, Rviz works fine. If someone could help me with this issue, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352194/rviz-interact-mode-stuck,-can%27t-move-mouse-without-rotating-environment/) by [pbjSandwiches](https://answers.ros.org/users/54582/pbjsandwiches/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Restarting the entire machine fixed the problem for me, I'm not sure why...

---

Originally posted by [pbjSandwiches](https://answers.ros.org/users/54582/pbjsandwiches/) with karma: 36 on 2020-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on 2021-06-17**:
how to restrat entire machine